# Is there an SHA224 implementation for .Net?

Tags: .net, sha2

Does .Net have a built-in implementation of SHA224 available for use or a way to get one of the existing .Net SHA implementations to do 224?

I found this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2009/01/23/sha-2-support-on-windows-xp.aspx) which seems to suggest there isn't and won't be a Microsoft implementation of SHA224 so does anyone know of a good 3rd party implementation?

Any solution that relies on P/Invoke is not acceptable as needs to be fully managed code as I need to support multiple platforms (.Net, Silverlight, Windows Phone and Mono)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out this project on codeplex: http://hashlib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/60118#514361

Comment: Yes that does what I want.  I'd rather not have to add a full blown DLL as an additional dependency to my APIs DLL just to satisfy one tiny point of a specification :-(  May not have a choice though if I can't persuade the W3C working group to drop SHA224 from the draft specifications

Comment: You don't need a full blown DLL, you just need to add the code from the following 11 classes in that project: `ArrayExtensions.cs`, `Converters.cs`, `Hash.cs`, `HashBuffer.cs`, `HashCrypto.cs`, `HashCryptoNotBuildIn.cs`, `HashResult.cs`, `IHash.cs`, `IHashInfo.cs`, `SHA224.cs`, `SHA256Base.cs`

Comment: @Chris Yes but that is still a lot of classes to dump into my code just to support one tiny part of the specification but I guess I will have to do it

Comment: @Chris Took a little bit of fiddling to convert the code back to C# 3 but successfully integrated the code in my project now.  Added a few extra files so I can support MD5, SHA384 and SHA512 in Silverlight based builds

Comment: @RobV good to hear! I never even knew there was a SHA382 until you posted it!