# is there an implementation of the SHA-224 algorithm for c# in .Net?

Tags: c#, cryptography, sha2

as the title says, is there an implementation of the SHA-224 algorithm for c# in .Net? I can't seem to find any reference through it. 
thanks a lot in advance

Comment: A quick search in Google should help you. Are you expecting us to do search for you..

Comment: I didn't mean you didn't search at all - but still Google more you should find some reference is what I meant .. I did and I got it on the first page.. So wrote the comment see answer..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an SHA224 implementation for .Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724720/is-there-an-sha224-implementation-for-net)

Answer (score 2):

There is not one within the default install of .NET. The only SHA-2 algorithms are 256, 384, and 512.

External libraries may exist, but an answer is outside the scope of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

There is no in-built library, but you can find code here http://hashlib.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/60118#514361
Hope this help.