# How to calculate SHA512/256 in .Net 6?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, sha512

How to calculate SHA512/256 or SHA512/224 without using external library?

In .Net 6, SHA512 hash can be calculated[(documentation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.sha512?view=net-6.0). Here is my example:

```
    public string GetHashStringSHA512(string data)
    {
        using (SHA512 sha512 = SHA512.Create())
        {
            byte[] bytes = sha512.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data));

            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                builder.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x2"));
            }
            return builder.ToString();
        }
    }
```

Comment: `SHA512.Create()` is using an encryption library. Where do you think the class comes from? Why would you want to do it yourself instead of using well-tested, secure libraries that already exist?

Comment: I think you may misunderstand what is meant by truncated SHA512. Truncated SHA512 variants are not truncations of the output digest - they're functionally different hash algorithms. You can't derive a SHA-512/N hash from the SHA512 hash of the same input.

Comment: Then, there is no method for `SHA512/256` or `SHA512/224` in .Net `System.Security.Cryptography`, and we have to use `external library`. @KenWhite @Brian

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46310836/is-there-an-implementation-of-the-sha-224-algorithm-for-c-sharp-in-net

Comment: @AkifT Try Bouncy Castle, even if you cannot use the library you may be able to extract the code due to the licensing. Of course, just extracting the algorithm may be tricky due to how the code is structured, but it is certainly possible.

Comment: @Brian Well, just a few constants really, but yeah, enough to make the inner state / output incompatible (and that's deliberate)

Comment: If you are computing a password hash, you can use [Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=netframework-4.7.2) and pass `HashAlgorithmName.SHA256` or `HashAlgorithmName.SHA512` to the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted in the comments, it appears that the .Net library has not implemented SHA512/256 or SHA512/224.

To calculate SHA512/256 or SHA512/224 *without* using external library, the [specification](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.180-4.pdf) would need to be implemented. There's a [document on the Cryptology ePrint Archive that includes some sample code](https://eprint.iacr.org/2010/548.pdf). See also the [NIST example](https://csrc.nist.gov/CSRC/media/Projects/Cryptographic-Standards-and-Guidelines/documents/examples/SHA512.pdf). There are a variety of open source solutions as well to use as a starting point for your own code, such as the [SHA512 library at wolfSSL](https://github.com/wolfSSL/wolfssl/blob/master/wolfcrypt/src/sha512.c) that includes both SHA512/256 and SHA512/224.